# Does docker container cache the MySQL query results?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, caching

I think docker container is caching MySQL query result in container itself. I did one quick round of testing

1. Truncated the table
2. Trigger the job which runs on docker container(hits the MySQL to fetch the data)
3. Still I can see MySQL queries are returning data from table. 
   We are not using application/DB level caching. So I believe this is the docker container which is caching the data.

My application is using python 3 , flask and mysql-connector-python==8.0.5 connector. MYSQL version is 5.6.

If docker container caching the data then how we can avoid/remove the cache? Any help here will be appreciated.

Note - When I restart the container then  it did not returned any data for same query for which we were getting the data before restarting the container.

Comment: Your NOTE is bit confusing, in both the cases you are referring to "restart the container". Could you post what commands used in both the scenarios?

Comment: This issue is resolved , DB level property *isolation_level* was set to "repeatative_reads" which was causing catching of result if you call same query multiple time then it was returning the same result which was hold in fist call. Setting this level to *READ COMMITTED* solved my issue